# vue,nuxt тестовое задание страница пользователя

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify

вот мое тз:
Создать приложение Профиль пользователя.

Пользователь при запуске приложения видит форму авторизации, вводит логин-пароль, попадает на страницу своего профиля с данными: имя, имейл, фото.

Ответы всех запросов (авторизация, получение данных) имитируются (mock).

Требования

1. Использование vuejs
2. Использование nuxtjs
3. Использование vuetify (дизайн значения не имеет)

Помогите разобраться с логикой работы и в правильном направлении я думаю?
У нас две страницы одна - авторизация, вторая данные. Если бы был бэкенд с бд, то нет вопросов.
Авторизацию нужно реализовать с nuxt auth?
Я не понимаю куда идут данные после авторизации и с чем они сравниваются. И от куда берутся данные для пользователя ( имя фото email) если бд нет?

Comment: Если они вам не дали тестовое апи, то тогда как вариант хранить их в локал сторедж

Comment: Спасибо, а nuxt auth нужен?